# Compilation error in formatting an out put in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java. I created a program and was getting an compilation error in this line:

```java
format("Pi is %f to 4 d.p.%n", pi);
```

The error is

> can't type double and String in one print stream.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you include the code snippet that you are using? To me it seems that you are not passing enough arguments to the format method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `format("Pi is %f to 4 d.p.%s", pi, myString);`. The `%s` is a placeholder for a `String`. You also have to provide your String `myString` as the second argument, as you can see.